# Angular 2+ is it possible to avoid global css?

Tags: angular

The title might be alittle missleading. I do currently have a angular SPA inside a .NET MVC application, inside of an area. but i am faced with global css already existing that affects the SPA.

So my question is. Is it possible to exclude specific global css files from affecting my components?

Comment: You could define global css with a classname and only target things that have that class

Comment: Global css is global. Don’t reuse those classes in your spa. This is an argument for always prefixing your css btw. Why are you putting your angular app in an area of a .net app though? It can be a subdomain or an existing app, but if you’re putting it actually within an existing page, then this is a bad idea but maybe use an iframe

Comment: Well, it's called global for a reason. Maybe yo ushould make it specific to avoid using it implicitly in your SPA ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use ViewEncapsulation.Native, no styles from the outside can affect your component:

```
@Component({
  encapsulation:  ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
```

Comment: Native is now deprecated in favor of ShadowDOM implementation. The reason for the change is that the Native ViewEncapsulation uses the deprecated version of ShadowDOM, and the new one uses the current version of the standard. (For the browsers that support it)